# How application behaves when updated from Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

I'm building sandboxed OSX app (with embeded helper app that is running on the background) that will be delivered through the Mac App Store and I'm not sure how update will affect app life cycle.

- What will happen with running app, when user hits update in app
  store?
- What will happen with running background helper app when user hits
  update in app store?
- Are apps installed under different accounts updated separately?

Thanks for any help, documentation for sandboxed apps doesn't have any information about update process.